# Replacing pandas column value with value in parenthesis, with comma in front

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where one column contains names, and part of it is in parenthesis, like so:

```
Names
Apple (juicy)
Banana (crunchy)
Grape (sour)
```

I want to change it to the following format:

```
Names
Apple, juicy
Banana, crunchy
Grape, sour
```

How can this be accomplished using pandas and regex?  I've tried this:

```
df['Names'] = df1['Names'].str.replace(r"\s+\(.*\)",", " + r"\(.*\)")
```

but the problem is in the last bit ( r"(.*)" ), where I don't know how to successfully transfer whatever is inside the parenthesis.  With the above code, I'm getting this:

```
Names
Apple, \(.*\) 
Banana, \(.*\) 
Grape, \(.*\)
```

Comment: Why regex? That is what is causing you issues and you don't need it. `.replace(' (', ', ').replace(')', '')` is easier to write and understand and communicates your intent more clearly.

Comment: Hm, I get this error: sre_constants.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 1

Comment: Looks like you have to escape some characters in the dataframe accessor: `df['Names'].str.replace(' \(', ', ').str.replace(')', '')`. Or use `apply`like suggested in an aswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing group and refer the captured characters in the replacement part through back-reference.

```
df['Names'] = df1['Names'].str.replace(r"\s+\((.*)\)", r", \1")
```

Comment: I think you mean df['Names'] = df1['Names'].str.replace(r"\s+\((.*)\)", r", \1")  which works! Thank you!

Comment: @ilee You mean a regex with unescaped brackets? No, I didn't mean that. see https://regex101.com/r/uyRFy5/1

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use `regex`?

You can do this

```
df['Names'] = df.Names.apply(lambda x: x.replace('(','').replace(')',''))
```

That would remove any parenthesis in any string.